# Netty WorkerPool under high load

Tags: java, netty

I have a custom webapp built on Netty with 64 Workers. I am trying to avoid long lived connections by sending Connection:Close headers after every 100 requests.

So under normal load I observe that all NettyChannels are closed after either 100 request on each pipeline or 1 request (client using non-persistent connection). But as the load increase I see a behavior where Channels start closing even before 100 requests. I doubt there could be some thread contention but I not able to figure out how to accurately make that reasoning.

For tracking request I have a simple handler attached to each pipeline. Example code

```
public class SimpleHandler extends SimpleChannelHandler {

    private final AtomicLong requestCount = new AtomicLong(0);

    public SimpleHandler(final HttpServerConfig httpServerConfig,
                                       final HttpConnectionMonitorMetricUtil httpConnectionMonitorMetricUtil) {
        uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    }

    @Override
    public void channelConnected(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) {
        requestCount.set(0);
        log.warn("Generating a new Handler:" + uuid);
        log.warn("Channel Connected " + ctx.getChannel().getRemoteAddress() + " " + ctx.getChannel().getLocalAddress() + ". Request Count was" + requestCount.get());
        ctx.sendUpstream(e);
    }

    /**
     * Invoked when a {@link Channel} was disconnected from its remote peer.
     */
    public void channelDisconnected(
            ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        ctx.sendUpstream(e);
        log.warn("Channel Disconnected by handler " + ctx.getChannel().getRemoteAddress() + " " + ctx.getChannel().getLocalAddress() + ". Request Count was" + requestCount.get());
    }

    public void channelClosed(
            ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelStateEvent e) throws Exception {
        log.warn("Channel Closed by handler " + ctx.getChannel().getRemoteAddress() + " " + ctx.getChannel().getLocalAddress() + ". Request Count was" + requestCount.get());
        ctx.sendUpstream(e);
    }
```

It seems under high load when more Channels are managed by same number of worker thread there is some kind of contention. I am trying to justify my assumption but if there is already a post or article depicting this it will be really helpful.

Comment: Are you sure that channels are closed by Netty on your side?

Comment: I think so, between this post and today I have some more finding. But the connection is closed because of idle state of connection. What I am observing netty closes connection if channel buffer receives no bytes, I earlier thought there maybe some idle time before which netty closes connection, But there is none I guess in Netty by default.

Comment: Netty has tools like `IdleStateHandler`, `ReadTimeoutHandler`. Are there any other handlers in the pipeline except `SimpleHandler`? It would be appropriate to list the code that creates the pipeline.

Comment: There is another which is just handles Simple Request processing. I wasn't aware of the handlers mentioned by you. Seems there is some code I should dig into to get more knowledge of handling these cases. Thanks!!